# Fuzzy diff n by n files

Tags: diff

I want to know the individual difference between n files, so similar to this:

```
parallel --tag 'diff {1} {2} | wc -l' ::: * ::: *
```

A big problem here is binary files, and a single megalong line will count the same as a short line.

How do I generate a fuzzy diff over n files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ssdeep` to generate a hash file:

```
ssdeep `find .  -type f` > hash
```

This will give the pairs with 90% <= similarity < 100%:

```
ssdeep -m hash `find .  -type f` | grep -E '9[0-9].$'
```

This only works if long stretches (blocks of around 1% of file size) are the same.